# MS Word 2013 Navigation Pane Context Menu

Tags: ms-word, vsto, word-2013

Using MS office 2013:

Does anyone know how I can get the CommandBar item for the Context menu that appears when right clicking an item on the navigation pane?

I want to add some extra options for performing on the range returned by the 'Select heading and content' button.

I can get the navigation pane using Application.CommandBars("Navigation"), but I can't for the life of me seem to be able to find the Context menu associated with this pane. I have even iterated all commandbars and their controls to look at the caption, and I can't even find a commandbar with a control that has the caption SubHeading.

Any ideas are welcome, I don't mind going down the CustomXml route as I am building a VSTO addin, I just want to be able to add buttons to the context menu and get the range for the selected heading and content.

UPDATE 1: Add screenshot of the context menu in question:
[image]

UPDATE 2:
Going down the CustomXml route as suggested by Eugene, I am still hitting a wall when I try to customise the menu:

Using the most recent CustomUI documentation from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=727 it suggests that the idMso of the context menu for the navigation pane is ContextMenuNavigationPane, but the following xml yields no results (it does work when adding to ContextMenuText).

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
  <contextMenus>
    <contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuNavigationPane">
      <button id="SomeNavButtonIAdded" label="Some Button i added" />
    </contextMenu>
  </contextMenus>
</customUI>
```

Answer (score 0):

What context menu exactly do you want to customize? Could you take a screenshot?

The fact is that Command bars are not used any longer (were deprecated). The only possible way to customize the context menus in Office 2013 is to use the Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI). You can read more about that in the following articles in MSDN:

- [Customizing Context Menus in Office 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee691832%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: Hey Eugene, thanks - I added a screenshot. I am perfectly comfortable going down this route but I can't seem to find anything that documents the names of all of the context menus or any way to find the name of a given menu except iterating the commandbars!

Comment: Unfortunately not all context menus can be customized. MS simply didn't publish the required IDs for them. See [Office 2013 Help Files: Office Fluent User Interface Control Identifiers](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36798).

Comment: It's listed in the latest list of idMso tags that they published, and ContextMenuNavigationPane is listed as available in word 2013 but it just doesn't work! :(

Comment: p.s. the most up to date list for office 2013 is here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=727

Comment: It may just be buggy, I've run into what seems to be buggy context menus before. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/f5796d41-5f33-4bf4-8828-05da04fb0384/contentmenulisttable-contextmenutablewholelinked-list-in-table

Answer (score 0):

Try the following for labelling all the commandbars (context menus, too) with their names.  I find it helpful when I customize them.  However, I think the names are not always the name you need for the ribbon xml.

One thing, the navigation pane context menu that the original post is referring to does not get labelled.  Is it not a a commandbar?

```vb
Sub LabelAllCommandBars()
    'Use this to label the command bars to see what their names are for use in the
    'customizations of commandbars.
    
    Dim myLabelCtrl As CommandBarButton
    Dim myLabelName As String
    Dim cb As CommandBar
    
    For Each cb In Application.CommandBars
        With cb
            myLabelName = cb.Name
            On Error Resume Next
             'Don't use the Before:= parm, some Controls/menus will raise a "Subscript
             'out-of-range" error. Just let it add it to the end/bottom.
            Set myLabelCtrl = cb.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton, Temporary:=True)
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Not myLabelCtrl Is Nothing Then
                myLabelCtrl.Caption = "Menu Name = " & myLabelName
                myLabelCtrl.Style = msoButtonCaption
            End If
        End With
    Next
End Sub

Sub ResetAllCommandbars()
    Dim cb As CommandBar
    Dim strName As String
    
    On Error GoTo cbError
    'There are a few, "Resume Reading" and "Ribbon" that raise error when attempt to Reset
    For Each cb In Application.CommandBars
        strName = cb.Name
        cb.Reset
    Next
cbError:
    Resume Next
End Sub
```